# Как добавить нулевой байт в файл Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe2

Столкнулся с проблемой в Delphi. Имеется файловая переменная F: File. Как в нее добавить нулевой байт? Это нужно осуществить с помощью процедуры BlockWrite.

Comment: Эмм.. Объясните на примере, пожалуйста. Пока что-то не понятно

Comment: Допустим у меня есть файловая переменная  F: File of Byte. В нее я могу записать нулевой байт следующим образов: Write(F, '#0'). А если тип просто File, то необходимо использовать вместо Write процедуру BlockWrite. Но через неё записать нулевой байт у меня не получается.

Comment: "записать нулевой байт у меня не получается" - покажите.

Comment: Вот так получилось, работает: BlockWrite(F, '#0', 4). Но правильно ли это?

Comment: Нет, это неправильно. Что означает параметр `4`?

Comment: Procedure BlockWrite(Var F : File; Var Buf; Count : Word
                                     [; Var Result : Word]);                                                              
Процедура BlockWrite записывает Count или меньшее количество записей в файл F из блока памяти, начинающегося с первого байта, занятого переменной Buf. Получается это количество записей, но если я там ставлю число 1, то записывает в файл # вместо #0

Comment: Зачем мне эта "сигнатура"? Я это и так знаю.

Comment: Почему Вы поставили туда число `4`?

Comment: Поставил, потому что с этим числом записывает в файл то, что мне нужно. Я не сильно в этом разбираюсь и, если, это неправильно, то подскажите как необходимо делать

Comment: А что, вот так не работает `BlockWrite(F, 0, 1)`?

Comment: И почему бы не использовать TFileStream?

Comment: С BlockWrite(F, 0, 1) выводит решетку без нуля

Comment: Кто куда выводит?

Comment: Извиняюсь, записывает (не выводит) в файл, который привязан с помощью AssignFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  ...
  b: byte;
begin
  ...
  b := 0;
  BlockWrite(F, b, 1);
```

---

> BlockWrite(F, '#0', 4)
>
> но если я там ставлю число 1, то записывает в файл # вместо #0

Потому что Вы пишете в файл кусок строки, залезая за ее конец.

Как объявлена переменная `F`, и как открыт файл?

Comment: F: File;                                                                                         
AssignFile(F, FileName);
Reset(F);

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо

Comment: @pharaxx Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score -1):

В паскале, а затем и в языках/средах программирования, выросших из него, принято использовать типизированные файлы. Это значит, что компилятор/линкер автоматически предложат наилучший путь записи данных в файл таким образом, чтобы затем используя тот же типизированный файл, их прочитать.
Пример:

```
var
  f1: file of byte;
  a:byte;

begin
  AssignFile(f1, 'c:\temp\fileofbytes.dat');
  Rewrite(f1);
  a:=0;
  Write(f1, a); // вот ваш ноль
```

и так далее, вы можете писать в файл данные побайтово. На самом деле, это очень неоптимально, но если вам там хочется, - пожалуйста. Зато не ошибётесь: каждый раз, когда будете использовать

```
  Read(f1, a);
```

будет считываться именно байт. Если использовали `file of string` - будет строка (на самом деле лучше использовать Text/TextFile, и тогда мы можем работать с текстовыми файлами) , и так далее.

Другой вариант (мы не рассматриваем потоки и другие разумные подходы в Delphi/Lazarus/Pascal.ABC и т.п, хотя они гораздо удобнее, быстрее...) - использовать нетипизированный файл:

```
var
  f2: file;
  a:byte;
  s:string;
```

и в него вы можете писать, что угодно, однако, должны помнить о том, что и разбираться, что за данные вы считали - это ваша проблема.

```
begin
  AssignFile(f2, 'c:\temp\file_simple.dat');
  Rewrite(f2);
  a:=0;
  BlockWrite(f2,a,1); // вот тут вы записали ваш ноль
  s:='Привет, мир!';
  BlockWrite(f2,s,length(s)); // а вот тут строка ушла в тот же файл
```

Comment: Чушь пишите. Особенно про строки. В Delphi `string` это указатель

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Неужели? Во-первых, я писал про паскаль, но многое осталось и в delphi.Во-вторых, изначально string не был указателем. Он теперь в Delphi - shortstring (но всё ещё можно опцией компилятора ограничить использование string только как shortstring). В этом, кстати, часто проявляются ошибки тех, кто привык к старому string, и продолжает работать с новым (который действительно указатель) теми же методами, например использовать в записях и т.п.

Comment: Хм... Опять голландский синдром? Изначально строки в паскале и делфи - не указатели. Вот неплохая статья: http://www.cyberguru.ru/programming/delphi/strings-details.html?showall=1

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov Изначально в Delphi это когда? Delphi1? Ничего, что у автора вопроса в метках delphi-xe?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov У автора в метках всё скопом. И pascal тоже, как ни странно. Но это не важно. Delphi 10.3.3 (последняя на данный момент версия) тоже поддерживает короткие строки не как указатели.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Поддерживает. В виде отдельного типа. О чем в ответе ни слова

Comment: @AntonShchyrov не согласен про отдельный тип. Ну, совсем

Comment: @ViktorTomilov В чем? В том, что ShortString это принципиально другой тип?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А это зависит от типа компиляции. Более того, string долгое время был визитной карточкой паскаля, а затем и delphi, впрочем, и остался и даже перетёк в другие языки. Далее, какой тип будет использоваться в случае file of string, как вы думаете? Вы же из-за это "прикопались" к ответу, так? Так вот, в этом случае будет использоваться shortstring, иначе нельзя.

Comment: _Прикопался_ я из-за этого `BlockWrite(f2,s,length(s));`

Comment: Ну и ваши домыслы о том, что `file of string` будет объявляться как `file of ShortString` неверны. При попытке такого объявления будет банальная ошибка компиляции `[dcc32 Error] E2155 Type 'string' needs finalization - not allowed in file type`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov А у меня никаких ошибок компиляции не возникает :P И чтобы избежать взаимных обвинений а ля "у вас не те консервы в консерватории", как было с год назад, вот пруф: youtu.be/K4fhWGiBCco   Delphi 10.1, дома другой купленной нет

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Проверил на XE3 и Delphi Rio (10.3) и там, и там ошибка есть [XE3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFkqO.png), [Rio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxjuG.png)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Смотрите опции компилятора или ещё что-то. Мне нечего добавить. Если я работаю со строками как с указателями (ANSIString, UnicodeString, Widestring) - работает как с указателями. С короткими - работает как с короткими (а с ними, уж поверьте, приходится работать постоянно - API к приборам требуют record со строками именно как shortstring). В понедельник могу сделать то же самое на 10.3.3, у одного из студентов стоит бесплатный пробный релиз. Вроде как где-то есть старый XE2 с лицензией, могу попробовать и его. Но вот ни разу не было проблем.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Кстати, BlockWrite(f2,s,length(s)) тоже работает. Может, AlexeyKozlov прав, и у вас голландский синдром? :) Не дай, Б-г, конечно

Comment: @ViktorTomilov По-моему, вы тут со string конкретно не правы. Да, в целях **[обратной совместимости](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/String_Types_(Delphi))** Delphi поддерживает как сам тип ShortString, так и возможность задать алиас string <=> ShortString. Но это для **исключительного случая** и отвечая на вопрос, стоит это отдельно оговаривать. Измените в своём ответе строки на ShortString и вопросов не будет.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov И да, в Delphi 10.3.3 у меня уже никак не получается сделать строки по-умолчанию короткими. Настройки проекта и директива `{$LONGSTRINGS OFF}` уже не работают. В справке [написано](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Long_strings_(Delphi)) что эта директива уже считается устаревшей и компилятор её игнорирует. Так что остаётся только явное указание типа ShortString.

Comment: @zed Скажем так, я изменю свой ответ, но не так как вы думаете :) В нём есть неточность, но иная. А то, что вы приводите - некорректно. Ибо проверено на _последних_ версиях Delphi и работает. Мне привести видео-доказательство?

Comment: Прошу прощения, интернет+PCChanel из гостиницы тупит. Следует читать так в дополнение к предыдущему сообщению:P.S. Увы, что Borland, что последователи (да, в принципе, очень многие разработчики этим страдают: взять MS с их MCB, да что угодно) очень долго соблюдают совместимость. Иногда это требует чрезмерных пассов руками со стороны разработчиков, есть ряд недокументированных опций компилятора (а что вы хотели? :)) Читайте "серые доки".

Comment: Если у вас оно работает на версии 10.3.3, то интересно посмотреть на видео-доказательство. Потому как у меня не работает и документация на моей стороне. http://prntscr.com/qsbnuo